# How to format "and" or "&" in a three-line header or title

Tags: conjunctions, typography, ampersand

I need to know which formatting is more appropriate. Should I place the connecting *and* or *&* at the end of second line or at the beginning  of the third line?

Here is what I mean:

> Lorem ipsum
>   Blah Blah **and/&**
>   Blah Blah

or

> Lorem ipsum
>   Blah Blah
>   **and/&** Blah Blah

Which one looks better?

PS: I’m asking this for a poster design, so it has to be split across three large lines.

Comment: If it's for a poster, different rules apply. I've designed hundreds of posters. **&** is still to be  deprecated, but it might be necessary or even desirable in some circumstances (eg "Dinner & Dance"), and the end result depends entirely on aesthetics. You would actually be better off asking in GraphicDesign.SE, although you'll need to use the actual words in your question simply because it all hinges on how it actually looks.

Comment: This would be easy / If those three lines were written / To form a haiku :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the look of the first example, but that's just me. Still, I think most native speakers of English and other languages with a romanized alphabet (a, b, c,...) would prefer the first.

Answer (score 2):

Ampersands are generally used in one of two ways – in the titles of firms such as Freeman, Hardy & Willis and in dictionaries where space is limited.

In all other instances *and* should be used.

Comment: And what about its place? should I place it at the end of second line or at the beginning of the third line?

Comment: The first example before you break the line

Comment: That may not be what the OP asked.

Comment: They're also O.K. in various abbreviations, such as "Q&A", "R&B", and "R&R".